# Multivariable limit of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin (\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find Multivariable limit of $$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0) }\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
Limit is obviously zero, but my question is how to simplify it a bit more to make it more obvious?

Comment: Have  you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: A user said that $|\sin(\text{whatever})|\leq 1$, but he deleted his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$
0 \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \left| \sin \left( \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \right) \right| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
and by squeezing...

Comment: Thank you so much, edited.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you're just looking to simplify the expression, (since you know it's obviously zero), going to polar coordinates:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}r\times \sin\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$$
Setting $u=1/r$:
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac {\sin(u^2)}{u}$$

And since $\sin(x)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$...